# Does facebook have its own cache?

Tags: facebook, caching

While developing Facebook applications I have faced this problem many times that if I delete any image, then it appears on the application while testing, even I delete the whole file then, even, it is executed successfully, so I want to know "Does Facebook have its own cache from where files are executed?".

If so then is there any solution of this problem?

If not then why is happening this?

Best Regards & Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about image files (they reside in CDN) but facebook uses MemCached server to cache their stuff.

Answer (score 0):

It's not that it has cache but that its main backing store doesn't provide any more coherency than is strictly necessary. Coherency has a cost, so if you don't need it, it makes sense not to pay the cost.

When operations have no enforced order between them, they may complete as if they were executed in either order. If your retrieval and your delete have on enforced order, then they may complete as if they were executed in either order. This applies even if one operation receives its response before the other operation was sent.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding was that there was a cache. Especially for images and styles.
I have frequently made changes to css and updated images only to be left wondering why i can not see these updates.
I always change my css url to be something like styles/styles.css?time= which remedies everything.
In regards to the images , right click on the image in application and view in browser. Refresh to get the updated image and then go back to you application.